# remove a class if screen.height is lower than 460px

Tags: javascript, css

I have this project where I have a fixed nav, but the navigation is longer than screens under 460 px, så i want to remove that fixed nav, when the screen.height i lower than 460px. This is my code, I have tried 3 different things and it doesn't work:

```
// var ratio = window.devicePixelRatio || 1;
//var ScreenHeight = screen.height * ratio;    
// var ScreenHeight = widows.screen.height;
var ScreenHeight = window.screen.availHeight;

if (ScreenHeight < 460) {
    $('.nav-container').removeClass('sticky');
}

var headerHeight = $('header').height();
var main = 120;
main = document.getElementById("main").offsetHeight;
$(window).scroll(function () {

    if (main > 825) {
        var headerHeight = $('header').height();
        if ($(window).scrollTop() >= headerHeight) {
            $('.nav-container').addClass('sticky');
        } else {
            $('.nav-container').removeClass('sticky');
        }
    }
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you never update the variable `main` in the `scroll` callback, so if it doesn't pass once it never will.

Answer (score 1):

Have you try `$(window).height();` instead of `window.screen.availHeight`?

Answer (score 0):

You are computing the `main` value only once and, everytime the user scrolls, you use the old `main` value. You probably need to change this:

```
...
main = document.getElementById("main").offsetHeight;
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if (main > 825) {
        ...
```

To this:

```
...
$(window).scroll(function () {
    main = document.getElementById("main").offsetHeight;
    if (main > 825) {
        ...
```